# Find VC dimension

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, vc-theory

I'm studying theoretical machine learning at university, and I have this problem in textbook, that I have no Idea how to start.
In space $X=R^2$ are given two models $H_1$ (rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes) and $H_2$ (lines). We define a model $H_3$ such that every hypothesis is a combination of one hypothesis from $H_1$ and one from $H_2$. Prove or disprove that the model $H_3$ has a bigger **VC** dimension (Vapnik–Chervonenkis dimension) then the **VC** dimensions of the models $H_1$ and $H_2$.

I need to find **VC** of $H_1$, $H_2$, and combined of $H_3$.

Comment: examples of VC computation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension#Examples) but I fail to understand the $H_1$ and $H_2$ sets, in yout question

Comment: @NikosM. so the first is rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes and second are just straight lines. In textbook I found  that VC (H2)=3 and VC(H1)=4 but I don't know how to get the VC dimension of H3?

Comment: If you understand how $VC(H_1)$ and $VC(H_2)$ are derived then it can help derive the combined VC

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  The same exercise is posted here, so something has been copied from somewhere: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139171/755, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/93279/8560.

Comment: @NikosM. I understand and found that VC(H1)=3 and VC(H2)=4. But how can I combine them ?

Comment: Not so difficult, keep trying!